# How to limitate cpu usage with pyglet loop?

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm writing a music player, to be able to control the music reading, I create a thread in which I put a while loop.
My problem is that even if I limitate the loop with pyglet.clock.tick(), my cpu is at 100%.

Is there a way to reduce it ?

```
class PlayerThread(threading.Thread):

  stopnow = None
  player = None

  def __init__(self, player, file_path):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    self.stopnow = threading.Event()
    self.player = player
    source = pyglet.media.load(file_path)
    self.player.queue(source)

  def run(self):
    self.play()
    while not self.stopnow.isSet():
      pyglet.clock.tick()


  def play(self):
    if not self.player.playing:
      self.player.play()

  def stop(self):
    self.stopnow.set()

  def pause(self):
    if self.player.playing:
      self.player.pause()
```

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `clock.set_fps_limit(number_of_frames_per_second)` to set upper bound of framerate.

Comment: Thank you it's working! how to define how many fps needed to play a music ?

Comment: That's up to you ;), I didn't ever work with music, only graphics, but you can search something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24p to get things out.